# grpc python unary microservice unable to connect to another service

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, microservices, grpc

I have a simple microservice running hosting grpc.
I am trying to reach to that service from my machine. My client is unable to reach. I might be doing something wrong with my kubernetes config. I need advice from some Kubernetes and python grpc gurus to understand where I am missing anything.

Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpctest-service
  namespace: myproject
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mypod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 50051
      targetPort: 50051
```

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: GRPC
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  labels:
   app.kubernetes.io/name: mypod
  name: grpctest-ingress
  namespace: myproject
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <hostname>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: grpctest-service
          servicePort: 50051
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - <hostname>
    secretName: wild-tls-secret
```

Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 50051

CMD ["python3", "/app/unary_server.py"]
```

unary_server.py

```
 server.add_insecure_port('0.0.0.0:50051')
```

unary_client.py

```
        self.host = <hostname>

        self.server_port = 80
```

I tried changing port to 50051
It is still unable to reach.
What should I be doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I am able to reach to the microservice from another microservice using service IP address
So My ingress file should be wrong

Comment: Do you have ingress as LoadBalancer/NodePort ? Could you share more information about your environment? If you do not specify `service` type it will be created as `ClusterIP` which is reachable only inside cluster. Did you try to change your service to [NodPort Type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)

Comment: Ok I tried Nodeport with following settings
```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: my namespace
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mypod
  ports:
    - port: 50051
      targetPort: 50051
      nodePort: 30007
```

still same issue, How can ingress know where to connect?

Comment: Did you deployed `Nginx Ingress controller`? What if you will add `rules.http.paths.path: /` like in [Ingress docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) or you are trying to use Ingress with [defaultBackend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) ? What error you are receiving?